# Why when typing inside the onchangetext event it's not doing anything?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When the code in the event TextChanged was inside the event TextBoxURL_KeyDown it was working fine also with the logic i wanted. But then i had to press the enter key,  so i moved it to the TextChanged event but now when i type a valid in the TextBoxUrl nothing happens.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DownloadMultipleFiles
{
    public partial class AddNewDownloads : Form
    {
        public AddNewDownloads()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
            {
                if ((ctrl as TextBox) != null)
                {
                    (ctrl as TextBox).TextChanged += TextChanged;
                }
            }

            this.TextBoxURL.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(TextBoxURL_KeyDown); //add keyDown event
            if (TextBoxFilename.Text == "" || TextBoxBrowse.Text == "")
            {
                TextBoxFilename.Enabled = false;
                TextBoxBrowse.Enabled = false;
                btnOK.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void AddNewDownloads_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TextBoxURL_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) //validate the URL when you press the Enter key
            {

            }
        }
        private bool CheckValidUrl() // validate from clipboard
        {
            string isUrl = Clipboard.GetText();
            Uri uriResult;
            bool result = Uri.TryCreate(isUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult)
                && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
            return result;
        }
        private bool WriteValidUrl() // validate manual input 
        {
            string pattern2 = @"^http://www.[a-z].com$";
            Match match = Regex.Match(TextBoxURL.Text, pattern2);
            if (match.Success)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        private new void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckValidUrl() == true || WriteValidUrl() == true)
            {
                TextBoxFilename.Enabled = true;
                TextBoxBrowse.Enabled = true;
                btnOK.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                TextBoxFilename.Enabled = false;
                TextBoxBrowse.Enabled = false;
                btnOK.Enabled = false;
            }
            if (TextBoxURL.Text == "")
            {
                TextBoxFilename.Enabled = false;
                TextBoxBrowse.Enabled = false;
                btnOK.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That definition looks wrong...you're not implementing an event handler, you are covering one up.  Take the `new` keyword out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextChanged fires on exit of the textbox.  You might be looking for KeyDown or KeyUp, or KeyPress - probably KeyUp as this will allow you to capture what is in the textbox after the new character is added.